# Is there a safe way to install Ubuntu on my Android phone?

Tags: rom-flashing, linux, xiaomi

I have a Xiaomi Pocophone F1 with decent specs: Snapdragon 845, 6 GB RAM, and enough storage. I was wondering if there is a tried-and-tested way to install some Linux Distro on it (preferably Ubuntu) for some specific reasons. I've seen some YouTube clips, but their instructions are not fully clear, so I wanted to ask here. Can anybody here give me a walkthrough or point me to a resource I can follow? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There are two major problems for installing Linux on a smartphone: 1. the boot process is not "standardized" like on a PC (no BIOS/(U)EFI, ..). 2. The standard Linux kernel lacks support for a lot of components that can be found in typical Android smartphones because the manufacturer don't integrate their drivers and modifications in the standard kernel and instead providing customized kernels. Even for a common system like Raspberry standard Linux distributions do still not run perfectly on it (and Raspberrys are there for years, sold millions of times).

Comment: See the second part (How to boot Ubuntu on Android device?) of my answer to [How to boot Ubuntu persistent live USB on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/220677/how-to-boot-ubuntu-persistent-live-usb-on-android)

Comment: More details: [IS IT POSSIBLE TO INSTALL WINDOWS, iOS OR LINUX ON ANDROID DEVICE?](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/info-to-instal-windows-ios-linux-t3763961)

Comment: Also see: [Linux on Android and HW support](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218360/3573) as Termux/Andronix may give you the Linux-like (but not exactly) environment on your phone.

Comment: what is your usage case for this ubuntu? do you still want to use it as mobile phone with apps? what apps do you expect to run on this? or do you just need a linux shell for doing cmd line stuff?

Comment: https://devices.ubuntu-touch.io http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.meefik.linuxdeploy

Comment: [UserLAnd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tech.ula) is another Termux-like app for running some Linux distros on mobile. It can also be used to run some specific apps, like Firefox or GIMP. It seems to be a more-complete Ubuntu by default as it has sudo and most other standard commands, unlike Termux. Personally I like the ability to have multiple installations and keep one as a daily driver and playing around in the other and destroying it when it goes bad.